# AngularJS always including an object in an ngRepeat filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to always include certain objects that have a specific property value, regardless of the active filter.

**Example Description:** I am filtering by 'status: Production', which will list only employees whose status is in production. I edit an entry and save it, that object now has the `saving` property set to `true`. If I change the filter to `status: Offboarded` that entry will now be filtered out. I want to keep any objects with the `saving: true` property unfiltered.

**Example Filter:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeData | filter:{status: queries.status}
                                        | filter:{duties: queries.duties}
                                        | filter:queries.generalQuery">
```

I want to always include any `employee` who's `saving` property is `true`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a single filter function.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeData | filter: filterEmployees">
```

And your filter function would be something like this:

```
$scope.filterEmployees = function(employee) {
    if (employee.saving) return true;
    // rest of the filtering...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My actual `ngRepeat` filters are more complex than my example, something I would rather not reinvent the wheel on. Is there any way to do this that does not require me to re-roll all the filter behaviors that come with angular?

Comment: You can always use other filters in the filter function via $filter.

Comment: Yup, what just **Dylan** said! You don't have to reinvent anything. I can't really think of any other way to do it.